# Bracket minimization with a<b<c s.t. f(a)>0, f(b)=f(c)=0

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, optimization, continuity

Suppose I have a  function  f that is continuous (not necessarily unimodal) over real numbers, and  three points a < b < c s.t. f(a)>0, f(b)=f(c)=0.  I wonder whether this claim is right:

There must exist m of the open interval (a,c) so that

1) m is a local minimum of f, and

2) f(m)<=0.

I think the claim is correct,  but don’t see how to prove it. If it is correct, how can we prove it?

Comment: Hint: consider the minimum of $f$ in the interval $[b,c]$

Comment: I believe we should consider the maximum of f in the interval [b,c], rather than the minimum, because that makes the proof easier. Thanks, Crostul.